# How can I properly install cs50.h Library on OS X 10.10.1?

Tags: c, bash, macos, gcc, cs50

I'm attempting to install the cs50 library 
https://manual.cs50.net/library/#mac_os so that I can compile c code for the class on my OS X 10.10.1. Unfortunately, I'm having some problems.

Let me walk you through what I've done so far. As instructed in the above link, I entered the following commands into the bash terminal:

```
$ ls
cs50.c  cs50.h
$ gcc -c -ggdb -std=c99 cs50.c -o cs50.o
$ ar rcs libcs50.a cs50.o
$ rm -f cs50.o
$ chmod 0644 cs50.h libcs50.a
$ sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/include
$ sudo mv -f cs50.h /usr/local/include
$ sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/lib
$ sudo mv -f libcs50.a /usr/local/lib
$ cd ..
$ rm -rf library50-c-5
```

After seemingly installing the library correctly, I ran `gcc generate.c -o generate`to compile the file. I got the following error:

```
$ pwd
home/Developer/pset3/find
$ ls
Makefile    find.c      generate.c  helpers.c   helpers.h
$ gcc generate.c -o generate
generate.c:17:10: fatal error: 'cs50.h' file not found
#include <cs50.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
$
```

I also got the same error when I ran `gcc generate.c -o generate -lcs50`

Why is the cs50.h file not being found? Is the file being installed correctly?

I searched for similar questions but others seemed to be experiencing a slightly different problem:

- [Harvard CS50 Library , Need Help Installing on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963640/harvard-cs50-library-need-help-installing-on-mac-os-x)
- [Adding a header file to Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964005/adding-a-header-file-to-xcode)
- [cs50 library wont link to file in cs50 appliance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23749103/cs50-library-wont-link-to-file-in-cs50-appliance)

Comment: You need `-I /usr/local/include` and `-L /usr/local/lib` in the command line (and the `-L` must precede `-lcs50`).

Comment: OT: I *hate* that module. The header starts out with `typedef char* string;` and doesn't get any better. ugh.

Comment: @WhozCraig FWIW, the library is not meant for general purpose use. It is designed to facilitate teaching the CS50 programming course. In "Week 3" of the course, the instructor, David J. Malan, reveals that `string` is just an alias for `char*` and starts explaining what it means. Frankly, I'm impressed that they're still using C. The whole course is available online for free at http://edx.org/.

Answer (score 2):

After the installation of the cs50 library I added this to my ~/.bashrc file.

```
function make50 { gcc "$1".c -o "$1" -I /usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib -lcs50; }
```

then start a new terminal or just source the ~/.bashrc file in your current terminal

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now lets say you have a directory with a file called `generate.c` in it. You should be able to run `make50 generate` (without the ".c") and the function should call the compiler with all the arguments needed

```
user@macbook:~/project$ ls
generate.c
user@macbook:~/project$ make50 generate
user@macbook:~/project$ ls
generate   generate.c
```

You can add more library paths to your function in ~/.bashrc as needed.